# Dúvida para trazer dados do mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com a seguinte dúvida. Considere que tenho os seguintes dados de vendas:

Dois Estados ex: São Paulo (Atibaia, São Paulo e Campinas) e Paraná (Londrina, Curitiba, Cascavel).

```
| cidade    | estado | vendas |
|-----------|--------|--------|
| Cascavel  | PR     | 10     |
| Curitiba  | PR     | 8      |
| Londrina  | PR     | 3      |
| Campinas  | SP     | 3      |
| São Paulo | SP     | 5      |
| Atibaia   | SP     | 3      |
```

Preciso trazer as cidades dos seus respectivos Estados que possui o maior número de vendas.

Fiz esse comando: para fazer um count na cidade aí traz a soma, porém preciso separar agora as cidades. nesse caso teria que trazer São Paulo e Cascavel.

```
 select
  count(d_clientes.cidade_nome), f_pedidos.cliente_sk, d_clientes.cliente_sk, d_clientes.cidade_nome, d_clientes.estado_nome, d_clientes.estado_sigla 
 from
 f_pedidos 
 inner join d_clientes on f_pedidos.cliente_sk = d_clientes.cliente_sk  
group by d_clientes.cidade_nome
```

Comment: lol n entendi nada o enunciado , edita ai rsss - tipo posta sua estrutura do db e exatamente como vc quer ordenar.

Comment: acho que dá pra usar o MAX do SQL

Comment: @JasarOrion ele entende bem de SQL, top

Answer (score 3):

Podemos quebrar esse problema em duas partes. Primeiro precisamos contar a quantidade de vendas por cidade e estado:

```
SELECT cidade, estado, count(*) FROM vendas
GROUP BY cidade, estado
ORDER BY estado, count(*) DESC;
```

Com isso temos o resumo já ordenado.

```
| cidade    | estado | count(*) |
|-----------|--------|----------|
| Cascavel  | PR     | 10       |
| Curitiba  | PR     | 8        |
| Londrina  | PR     | 3        |
| São Paulo | SP     | 5        |
| Campinas  | SP     | 3        |
| Atibaia   | SP     | 3        |
```

E como encontrar a cidade que mais vendeu por estado?

Para isso precisamos incluir um *ranking* das cidades que mais venderam por estado, algo assim:

```
| cidade    | estado | count(*) | ranking 
|-----------|--------|----------|---------
| Cascavel  | PR     | 10       | 1
| Curitiba  | PR     | 8        | 2
| Londrina  | PR     | 3        | 3
| São Paulo | SP     | 5        | 1
| Campinas  | SP     | 3        | 2
| Atibaia   | SP     | 3        | 3
```

Isso pode ser feito de forma bem simples com uma *window function*. Colocando isso numa *subquery*, o trabalho final seria fazer um filtro onde o *ranking* é igual a 1:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT cidade, estado, count(*), 
      row_number() over (partition by estado order by count(*) DESC) as rank
    FROM vendas
    GROUP BY cidade, estado
    ORDER BY estado, count(*) DESC;
) AS sub
WHERE rank = 1;
```

Porém, o [MySQL não suporta window functions](https://veekaybee.github.io/mysql-window-functions/) :(

Para chegarmos ao mesmo resultado, é preciso algumas adaptações na parte referente ao *ranking*:

```
-- Não esqueça de definir as variáveis! Elas são importantes
SET @currcount = NULL, @currvalue = NULL;
SELECT cidade, estado, qtd_vendida FROM (
  SELECT *, 
      @currcount := IF(@currvalue = estado, @currcount + 1, 1) AS rank,
      @currvalue := estado AS bla
  FROM (
    SELECT cidade, estado, count(*) as qtd_vendida
    FROM vendas
    GROUP BY cidade, estado
    ORDER BY estado, count(*) DESC
  ) AS vendas
) AS ranking
WHERE rank = 1
```

Veja funcionando no [*SQL Fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d244c1/39).

Referências:

- http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/08/20-Window-Functions
- https://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269273/2099835